# FQL: what different between filter_key='others' and filter_key='owner'

Tags: facebook-fql

I don't see any documentation about that here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/

This is a FQL query for example:

```
select created_time,description,type,filter_key,permalink,message,actor_id from
```

stream where filter_key='nf'

filter_key='nf' 
filter_key='others'
filter_key='owner'

Comment: `owner` filters for posts made by the page/user itself, whereas `others` are the post by … well, others.

Comment: And what is filter_key='nf'?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comments the filter `owner` filters posts made by the owner. `others` filters posts other than the owner.

The best thing to do when you don't know is to try the queries and compare the responses.